# Multiple Submit button in Struts 1.3

Tags: struts, struts-1

I have this code in my JSP:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
..
..
<html:form action="update" >
  ..
  ..
  <html:submit value="delete" />
  <html:submit value="edit" />
  <html:sumit value="update" />
</html:form>
```

And this in the `struts-config.xml` file:

```
<action path="/delete" name="currentTimeForm" input="/viewall.jsp" type="com.action.DeleteProduct">
   <forward name="success" path="/viewall.jsp" />
   <forward name="failure" path="/viewall.jsp" />
</action>
```

Like the `delete` action, I have `edit` and `update`. It works fine, if I give the name specifically like `<html:form action="delete">` but, how to make it dynamically work for `update` and `edit`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have one form and multiple submit buttons. The problems is that a form can only submit to one action, no matter how many submit buttons you have inside the form.

Three solutions come to mind right now:

**1.** Have just one action where you submit everything. Once inside the Action class check what button was used to submit the form and perform the appropriate treatment based on that.

```
<html:form action="modify">
  ..
  ..
  <html:submit value="delete"/>
  <html:submit value="edit" />
  <html:sumit value="update" >
</html:form>
```

In the `ModifyAction.execute(...)` method have something like:

```
if (request.getParameter("delete") != null || request.getParameter("delete.x") != null) {
   //... delete stuff
} else if (request.getParameter("edit") != null || request.getParameter("edit.x") != null) {
   //...edit stuff
} else if (request.getParameter("update") != null || request.getParameter("update.x") != null) {
   //... update stuff
}
```

**2.** Have the action attribute of the HTML form changed using JavaScript before submitting the form. You first change the submit buttons to plain ones with click handlers attached:

```
<html:form action="whatever">
  ..
  ..
  <html:button value="delete" onclick="submitTheForm('delete.do')" />
  <html:button value="edit" onclick="submitTheForm('edit.do')" />
  <html:button value="update" onclick="submitTheForm('update.do')" />
</html:form>
```

With the handler:

```
function submitTheForm(theNewAction) {
  var theForm = ... // get your form here, normally: document.forms[0]
  theForm.action = theNewAction;
  theForm.submit();
}
```

**3.** Use a [`DispatchAction`](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-extras/apidocs/org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction.html) (one Action class similar to point 1) but without the need to test for what button was clicked since that's treated by the `DispatchAction`.

You just provide three execute methods properly named `delete`, `edit` and `update`. [Here is an example that explains how you might do it](http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-dispatch-action-example-1.html).

**In conclusion:** For number 1, I don't really like those ugly tests.... for number 2, I don't really like the fact that you have to play with the action form using JavaScript, so I would personally **go for number 3**.

Comment: really nice guidance given by you - +1

Comment: @user159088: What if using i18n? The value is also the button label.

Answer (score 0):

There is another simpler way to do this as follows:

In the ActionForm currentTimeForm, add a String property (example: buttonClicked).

In the jsp, in each of the html:submit tags add this property.

Now in the action execute method simply check the value of this property, ie.

```
if(currentTimeForm.getButtonClicked().equals("delete"){
}
else if((currentTimeForm.getButtonClicked().equals("edit"))
```

and so on...

Comment: i consider this as not efficient way of doing this. With 10 forms for instance that have double or triple submission buttons, you cant keep adding session or request variables or adding more variables to your bean.