# How to add tag <html:submit> dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts

I'm trying to create a simple HTML project using the Struts framework.
I'm trying to add dynamically the tag `<html:submit property="switchsubmit" ...... >`

I have created a table and I gave it the `id='idTable'`.
I have created a button which have the goal to add a new line in the table, this line contains a submit button created in tag based on Struts concept.

In the `onClick()` function of the button, I wrote the code as below:

```
var table = document.getElementById('idTable');

var row = table .insertRow(0);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
cell.style="border: 1px #376BAD solid;";

var submit = document.createElement("html:submit");  
submit.property="switchsubmit";
submit.value="Add";
cell.appendChild(submit);
```

I've been adapted All about the `struts-config.xml`.

Comment: does <html:submit> result in something else being generated and returned to the DOM? or is that literally the element that gets created.

Comment: I don't know much about struts, but wouldn't that be serverside code?

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386643/multiple-submit-button-in-struts-1-3

Comment: Dear @KevinB, yes is that literally the element that gets created

Comment: `html:submit` is not a HTML tag.

Comment: so have you any idea about this problem ?

Comment: Use html tag input with adequate attributes.

Comment: Its not compatible with the concept of struts !

Comment: It's not a Struts related, but JSP related.

Comment: yes man, i know, but my quest, is how to write it in Struts !

Comment: Manipulating DOM in the browser is not a Struts concept, you are right. If you want a Struts to render JSP tags for you you should call him via Ajax and request a dispatcher result.

Comment: Dear @RomanC, now you are so right (y), please put your comment as answer and i will check it as true (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are made a mistake by adding Struts tag `html:submit` to the DOM element. This tag is a JSP tag and should be compiled and executed on the server side not in the client browser via JavaScript. If you want the Struts to render JSP tags, you should make an Ajax call to the server which will execute an action and process JSP page or fragment and return a response with HTML content type, then you can *inner* HTML to the element with JavaScript.

Comment: Correct answer,Careful analysis.This is the answer that i am looking for.... Big Thanxs @RomanC (y)